# Does we start writing cloud functions for firebase locally?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm going to use cloud functions for firebase to recursively delete documents and collections in Firestore that is triggered by HTTP request (I'm using HTTP Callable function specifically). I have found some useful information from the following links:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

But I'm not sure about one thing: It looks like from the tutorial, the functions are written locally and then deployed to cloud server. So where do I keep all the functions and their dependencies? If I keep the local written function within my android project, then each time when I update the function locally I will have to publish a new version of the app, which is too much work. Is it ok to start the local written function in another folder other than the android project? Also, if I want to start writing the function directly at cloud functions at GCP (so that I can update the function in cloud server), where can I get the dependencies files such as package.json, package-lock.json and .eslintrc.json etc.? I didn't find useful tutorial to that. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions, first you can keep your functions and dependencies anywhere as long as you have access and logged your account to the CLI with the right project configured in it. Each time you update your function locally then yes, you have to redeploy it.

If you want, you can consider setting up [CI/CD with your Firebase Functions](https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-continuous-deploying-with-cloud-build/) so you can automate deployments whenever you hit commit on master and staging branch of your repo.

Second, you can start the local written function anywhere, as long as it contains the right dependencies for your app. As Doug mentioned, it doesn't matter how your files are organized.

And third, the dependencies files such as package.json, package-lock.json, and .eslintrc.json is something that you need to provide on your own. I suggest that you read through their docs and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

> If I keep the local written function within my android project, then each time when I update the function locally I will have to publish a new version of the app, which is too much work.

That's not true.  It doesn't really matter where you project files are organized. You can still deploy the function whenever you want.  It's completely separate from your app code.

> Is it ok to start the local written function in another folder other than the android project?

If that's your preference, then do it.  As I mentioned, it doesn't matter how your files are organized.

> Also, if I want to start writing the function directly at cloud functions at GCP (so that I can update the function in cloud server), where can I get the dependencies files such as package.json, package-lock.json and .eslintrc.json etc.?

If you're having problems working with functions in the console, you should ask a separate question about that and indicate where you are stuck in that process.